# Must all routers support RIP in order for it to calculate distance?

Tags: rip, dynamic-routing

I'm just beginning to research the topic of RIP, and I'm left with a (perhaps stupid) question. According to a tutorial I read [here](http://www.9tut.com/rip-routing-protocol-tutorial), RIP exchanges routing information with its "direct" neighbours. My question is, what happens when a Non-RIP Router is sitting between two RIP routers as such:

```
RIP-Router-A ----- Non-RIP-Router ----- RIP-Router-B
```

Can RIP-Routers A and B exchange routing information in the above configuration?

- If not, is RIP rendered effectively useless in that configuration?
- If so, is the Non-RIP-Router counted in the hop calculation?

Of course, another possibility is that I'm completely misunderstanding RIP on some fundamental level. I welcome any constructive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, RIP routers interact with their direct neighbors. So if there's a non-RIP router in between, they won't interact with it.

Comment: So in the above example, RIP is rendered useless.

Comment: Pretty much. You'd use a combination of static routes, other routing protocols, and route injection to make the whole thing work.